# In python how do you deal with other encodings in domain names

Tags: python, string, email-spam, string-literals

I'm trying to parse domain names from the Message-ID field of an email that's been loaded from a file and compare it to the domain of the from field to see how well it matches up. Then I compare the distance using `nltk.edit_distance()`.

I'm using

`re.search('@[\[\]\w+\.]+',mail['Message-ID']).group()[1:]`

but one spam message has the following

```
mail2['Message-ID']
'<2011315123.04C6DACE618A7C2763810@\x82\xb1\x82\xea\x82\xa9\x82\xe7\x8c\xa9\x82\xa6\x82\xe9\x82\xbe\x82\xeb\x82\xa4>'
```

So when I try and match that it doesn't return a match in `group()`

I can decode it in Shift_JIS, but don't know what to do with it from there
`<2011315123.04C6DACE618A7C2763810@これから見えるだろう>`

I don't want to try and check for every possible character encoding.

Any ideas of what I should do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [chardet project](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet), which uses an algorithm to guess the character encoding:

```
import chardet

text = '<2011315123.04C6DACE618A7C2763810@\x82\xb1\x82\xea\x82\xa9\x82\xe7' + \
    '\x8c\xa9\x82\xa6\x82\xe9\x82\xbe\x82\xeb\x82\xa4>'
cset = chardet.detect(text)
print cset
encoding = cset['encoding']
print encoding, text.decode(encoding)
```

Output:

```
{'confidence': 1, 'encoding': 'SHIFT_JIS'}
SHIFT_JIS <2011315123.04C6DACE618A7C2763810@これから見えるだろう>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind if I ever need to do something like this again, but I'm going with a simpler solution of using the repr(my_string) values to force it into ascii then stripping the \'s.